# How to Select Recurring Text in a File

Tags: python-2.7, file-writing

I'm Writing a code, where the user can input one option out of a multiple choice selection. Whatever answer they give, such as "a" or "b", gets written as either "Correct" or "Not Correct" into a separate text file, (StudentAnswers.txt).
*Obviously, the new text file will be filled with multiple lines of "Correct", and "Incorrect"*

This part has already been achieved, but can someone please show me how to create a code which reads the text file "StudentAnswers", and if the total number of recurring "Correct" values is greater or equal to half, print "Passed", or if not print "Fail"

Hope you guys Understand. Thanks.

Comment: W.H.Y.T  ?....................

Comment: Why not just run through the file counting up each Correct and Not Correct and if Correct>Not Correct pass.

Comment: Sorry user2097159 I don't quite understand your comment

Comment: Loop through the file. I'm guessing you are writing the Correct and Not Correct on new lines.  And keep a rolling count of each. So if you see a Correct do `correct += 1`

Comment: Haha Sorry user2097159 I still have no idea, but thanks for the help. Not quite learned how to do the Conditional Rolling Count yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file lines and filter them either for "Correct" or for "Not Correct".

```
lines = open(file).readlines()
total = len(lines)
totalOK = len(filter( lambda x: x == "Correct\n") lines)
if totalOK >= total / 2:
    print "Passed"
else:
    print "Failed"
```

If you are not familiar with `lambda` and `filter` you can do it this way:

```
def countOK ( lines ):
    cnt = 0
    for i in lines:
        if i == "Correct\n":
            cnt += 1
    return cnt
...
lines = open( file ).readlines()
total = len( lines )
totalOK = countOK (lines)
if totalOK >= total / 2:
    print "Passed"
else:
    print "Failed"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I run the code, even with the text "Incorrect  Answer" inside the (StudentResponse) text file, it says "passed". Would you happen to know why and how to fix it?

Comment: Ah sorry man, your code worked fine, I just realized that only one line, either "Correct or Incorrect" will always produce a "Passed"

Comment: @Ash Glad i could help, you are weolcome.